# Generating random reachable platforms

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I use arc4random() and CGPointMake to regenerate platforms randomly throughout the single-view application.

However, how can I randomly regenerate the platforms near another platform for it to be reachable by the player/character of the game?

In other words, if I just set it randomly, one platform may be too far on the left and the other platform too far on the right, which would make it impossible for the character to reach the latter platform.

Thank you.

Comment: Sure. I'd love to accept your answer, but I do not see any checkmarks near your answers?

Comment: Don't feel forced to accept a wrong answer. @Zaph has not answered your question in any way and should not be pushing for you to accept in any way - it is poor form.I'll give you a hint in a second.

Comment: @davbryn I am not trolling for rep, it is just good advice. I up-voted the answer by 0x141E after it was corrected and IMO oit should be accepted.

Comment: Say somebody writing in Java comes across this problem. The answer is useless - it is a patch: it doesn't explain the logic (or answer the question); it isn't even Objective-C. (It isn't even a particularly useful solution - no offence intended).
Does @fer0n know where he was going wrong? If he doesn't, he shouldn't accept, since he didn't ask for code; he asked how to do it

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C not Java. While the answer by 0x141E is not objective-C methods is is "C" and Objective-C is "C". The part that is particularly good is the use of the transendentals along with a distance and angle (vector). It does miss height but that is just an extension of vector to 3 dimensions. Perhaps there could have been more discussion but the code does speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Declare various random number generating functions

```
#define kArc4RandomMaxValue      0xFFFFFFFF
static inline double skRandf() {
    return (double)arc4random_uniform(kArc4RandomMaxValue)/kArc4RandomMaxValue;
} 

static inline CGFloat skRandInRange (CGFloat low, CGFloat high) {
    return (skRandf() * (high - low) + low);
}
```

2) Define the min/max distances from the current platform to the new one

```
#define kMinDistance   100
#define kMaxDistance   200
```

3) Generate random x and y values based on the position of the current platform

```
CGFloat radius = skRandInRange(kMinDistance, kMaxDistance);
CGFloat angle = skRandf()*M_PI*2;
CGFloat x = radius * cosf(angle);
CGFloat y = radius * sinf(angle);

newPlatform.position = CGPointMake(currentPlatform.position.x+x, currentPlatform.position.y+y);
```

EDIT: Alternative method to calculate a new platform position

```
#define kRangeX         100
#define kMinYDistance   100
#define kMaxYDistance   200


CGFloat x = skRandInRange(-kRangeX/2, kRangeX/2);;
CGFloat y = skRandInRange(kMinYDistance, kMaxYDistance);;

newPlatform.position = CGPointMake(currentPlatform.position.x+x, currentPlatform.position.y+y);
```

Comment: Do not use rand() it is not very random, it has a default seed of 1 so will repeat the same sequence each time the app is launched. From the [OS X Man Pages](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/rand.3.html) "These interfaces are obsoleted by [arc4random(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/arc4random)

Comment: `arc4random()` has a range of 0 to (2**32)-1. See the link in the first comment. If you use arc4random_uniform() you can constrain the output to a smaller value without modulo bias.

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, but how do I set the platforms to only randomly regenerate at the top of "currentPlatform" instead of below "currentPlatform"?

Comment: Set angle = skRandInRange(0, M_PI) to generate a new platform to the left, right, or on top of the current platform.

Comment: In general, angle = skRandInRange(minAngle,maxAngle), where 0 points to the right of the platform, M_PI_2 points above, and M_PI points to the left.

Comment: What are the values for minAngle and maxAngle?

Comment: CGFloat radius = skRandInRange(40,45);
CGFloat angle = skRandInRange(M_PI, 0); I'm trying to keep the range between platforms not too far away from each other, but not too close either.

Comment: minAngle must be less than maxAngle. M_PI is greater than 0.

Comment: Apologies for the late response. Yes, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Break it down into simple steps:

```
You want a randomly placed platform

You want a reachable platform
```

I'm assuming you can randomly generate a platform. So, you have one problem to solve: Can the player reach it?

How far can your character jump horizontally? That's your maximum X distance. How high can he jump? That's your Y.if your random block is further than those, it is unreachable.

You can add more rules but the key is to work out where your character can reach and to then pick a spot *within these region*